# Subscript out of range - Find Next with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I get a "Subscript out of range" error message on this line:

```
Set NextRow = Sheets(xSheet).Cells.FindNext(After:=bookmark)
```

I have theoretically set my bookmark the minute I set my foundCell.

I'd like to:

1. Search for the first record matching the text in the 'Str' variable.
2. Using Excel's find feature, Find the text and which row it is on and populate the userform based on Cell values
3. Count the total results so I can do a [1] of [3] found somewhere on the userform
4. Use buttons to go backwards (Previous and Next) of my search results.

---

```
'Global Variables
Dim foundCell
Dim bookmark


Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

Dim Str
Dim FirstAddr
Dim xSheet

xSheet = "Office Spaces"

Str = "B-32"

    With Sheets(xSheet)

        Set foundCell = .Cells.Find(What:=Str, After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        Set bookmark = foundCell

    End With


    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then

        MsgBox ("""Bingo"" found in row " & foundCell.Row)

        UserForm1.location.Text = Sheets(xSheet).Cells(foundCell.Row, 3).Value
        UserForm1.office.Value = Sheets(xSheet).Cells(foundCell.Row, 2).Value
        UserForm1.floor.Value = Sheets(xSheet).Cells(foundCell.Row, 1).Value
        UserForm1.status.Value = Sheets(xSheet).Cells(foundCell.Row, 4).Value
        UserForm1.telephone.Value = Sheets(xSheet).Cells(foundCell.Row, 5).Value
        UserForm1.mobile.Value = Sheets(xSheet).Cells(foundCell.Row, 6).Value
        UserForm1.owner.Value = Sheets(xSheet).Cells(foundCell.Row, 7).Value
        UserForm1.notes.Value = Sheets(xSheet).Cells(foundCell.Row, 8).Value
        UserForm1.recnum.Value = 1
        FirstAddr = foundCell.Address

        Dim i

        Do Until foundCell Is Nothing

            Set foundCell = Sheets(xSheet).Cells.FindNext(After:=foundCell)

            i = i + 1

            If foundCell.Address = FirstAddr Then Exit Do
        Loop

        If i > 1 Then
            btnPrev.Enabled = True
            btnNext.Enabled = True
        End If

        UserForm1.recmax.Value = i

    Else
        MsgBox ("Bingo not found")
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub btnNext_Click()

Dim NextRow

Set NextRow = Sheets(xSheet).Cells.FindNext(After:=bookmark)

UserForm1.location.Value = Sheets(xSheet).Cells(NextRow.Row, 3).Value
UserForm1.office.Value = Sheets(xSheet).Cells(NextRow.Row, 2).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: In `btnNext_Click` you are referencing `xSheet` which is defined in your other Sub.

Comment: Try and `Dim` your variables explicitly. i.e. `Dim Str as String` and so on

Comment: Also you need to Find before you FindNext.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Better would be to `Dim someOtherName As String`. `Str` is hiding [a native VBA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function)... ;-)

Comment: Ok, please post that as the solution Brian and I will accept it.

Comment: @Comintern - quite right. I can't believe I didn't see that. Need more coffee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by `xSheet` not being assigned an appropriate value.  Why does it not have a value?  Because it is defined and assigned in one Sub and used in another Sub.  One way to fix this issue is to make `xSheet` global like you did for `bookmark`.

It would be good to also consider the advice from the other comments.  These suggestions would improve your code.